# Does an infinite AC bus which gets a load step experience any frequency sag?

Tags: ac, generator

I'd always imagined that the frequency sag experienced on an AC bus was a direct consequence of the mechanical slowing down of the alternator rotor/crank.

But is this truly the case? On an infinite bus, or perhaps more practically on a bus formed by an inverter, does a load step also translate to a frequency sag?

My understanding is that Voltage sag is what fundamentally happens on any type of circuit, but that frequency sag is only the case with mechanical (spinning) voltage sources (i.e. alternators).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a mechanical, spinning, voltage source, energy is stored in the rotational inertia of the alternators and turbines. It's this energy that is used to respond to step changes in load, and so yes, the rotational speed will drop until the mechanical power input can be increased to compensate.

In an infinite bus, only an infinitesimal change in average frequency is needed to release the energy for the step load change. However, the local machine(s) will still need to slow down for a moment, to create the phase shift that's needed to import energy from the more remote parts of the grid.

If the AC bus is entirely inverter driven, then what happens to the frequency depends on how the inverter has been programmed. It could respond to any load with the same frequency.

Or it could, if it's been designed to 'look like' a conventional grid, drop the frequency. Why? Some limited capacity supplies, so a small diesel or wind turbine on a small island for instance, may use automatic frequency sensitive load shedding switches on 'second class' loads like water heaters, to maintain supplies to the more important loads when the wind drops. This means an inverter could be used, and still work with the existing load shedding arrangements.

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer. 

Could you expand on two things: what is the physics behind the frequency change required on an infinite bus?

Second: on a bus with only an inverter present, what will the inverter "sense" that will make it react (in whichever way it's programmed to do so - whether it is in grid-forming or grid-tie)? It's almost like there's a "derivative of current" quantity somewhere, but I can't exactly make sense of it.

Comment: a momentary drop in frequency will create a phase lag, that's maths as much as physics. Two generators synchronised by being connected to the same grid are effectively very stiffly connected. If one turns faster and the other lags, power will be transferred from the leader to the lagger. An inverter that's running a small grid will be monitoring the current that's being demanded from it, and if it becomes excessive, will need to do something. Perhaps reduce frequency to provoke load shedding, then reduce voltage if that doesn't work, then shut down if that doesn't work.